# ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework & PostgreSQL, always face permission denied for 'Template1' when I access DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, postgresql

I have recently been attempting to use Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC that connects to a PostgreSQL database hosted on Heroku Connect via Npgsql -- A free .NET library that assists in connection. Hence, I am not creating a database from code, but instead querying from an external source. I have already set my Context class to look at the connectionstring that I provided.

However, I have constantly been hit with the error 42501: permission denied for database "template1" whenever I attempt to access my DbContext object. Anyone has any idea on what is going on?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24912916/postgresql-error-42501-permission-denied-for-schema) SO could help. The error code is originating from PostgreSQL. Review the database rights for the user you use connecting the database.

Comment: Hey Jeroen, thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, I tried that but to no avail. It continues to be hit with the same error. However, if I were to query by myself via Npgsqlconnection, it has no issues. Only when I run it through DbContext it faces this.